# How to fix "could find 'pry error'" in SublimeREPL

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3

I have this code:

```rb
# require 'io/console'

puts "Hello World"

# or what you can do is

print "What is your name ? "
name = gets
print name
```

I choose to use SublimeREPL by choosing

```
> Tools > SublimeREPL > Ruby > Ruby
```

since I can't accept inputs with the plain Ruby build system in Sublime Text 3, but I got this error:

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:310:in `to_specs': Could not find 'pry' (>= 0) among 107 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/Users/Abrham/.gem/ruby/2.5.0;C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0', execute `gem env` for more information
  from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:322:in `to_spec'
  from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
  from C:/Users/Abrham/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have `pry` gem installed? Run `gem list | grep pry`

Comment: I get no results 

$ gem list | grep pry

Comment: install it then :) `gem install pry`

Comment: I'm a newbie to the Ruby world, what does this mean?

Comment: C:/Users/Abrham/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Pry::InputCompleter (NameError)
Did you mean?  Pry::InputLock

I get this

Comment: `pry` is similar to Ruby's built-in `irb` but more complete. Obviously your system expects it so you need to install it.